# bring a <p> out of a div

Tags: asp.net, css

It's an asp project with `javascript` and `css`. I have taken the `java` from this site JonDesign's SmoothGallery demo.

Now I want to put the tag `p` which has the summary inside, out of the `div`,
by the way here is the code:

```
<div id="myGallery">
    <asp:Repeater ID="HeadLinesRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="imageElement">
                <h3><%# Eval("Title") %></h3>
                <div>
                    <p><%# Eval("Summary") %></p>
                </div>
                <a href='<%# "/NewsBody.aspx?NewsId=" + Eval("ID")  %>' title="متن کامل" class="open"></a>
                <img class="full" src='<%# "/Img/news/" + Eval("ID") + ".jpg" %>' />
                <img class="thumbnail" src='<%# "/Img/news/" + Eval("ID") + ".jpg" %>' style="width: 100px; height: 75px" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .jdGallery .slideInfoZone p {
            float: right;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            z-index: 1000000;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 92px;
            width: 300px;
            right: 670px;
            top: 220px;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 10pt !important;
            text-align: justify;
            color: white !important;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 60%;
            margin: 2px 5px;
            color: #eee;
        }
```

If I change position to the fixed it will be solved but ahen the I open the site in other resolution it would be unscrambled and goes to inside other `div`s.
It's my project for university please help me.

Comment: There's a javascript tag, but I see no javascript. Solution? Post your jacascript :)

Comment: Changing the html structure to place the paragraph where it belongs would be too easy, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just phisycally cut the `<p><%# Eval("Summary") %></p>` and paste it outside the div.

EDIT

What about styling the inner p with display:none, then create your own javascript (Do you have JQuery referenced in this page?) to grab all the paragraphs and append them elsewhere in the DOM.

But really it seams (from your comment) you need to change the javascript that manipulates the parent div to not depend on the inner paragraph, or change it to work with the paragraph in a different position in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I said it's a javascript (I know that much to bring it outside)
This <div id="myGallery"> div has java script, and I cannot change the inside.
So

Comment: Then you need to explain better the javascript part of your solution. Are you trying to move the paragraph element client side with javascript? into a pop-up dialog or something?

Comment: no it's an slide show for images for a news site,
it takes the pics from the repeater, the repeater makes 3  div with the class of imageElement and the javascript shows them.
And shows the '<h>' for title and '<p>' for summary.
the problem is here: it show both of the tags on the pic,
but I want the tag 'p' to be beside the pic not on it.
for that i asked this question.
Now if i change the position of 'p' to fixed in css I can but just in one resolution and if i change the resolution it will be unscrambled.